# Meaning of warning "ejb-api-3.0.jar' contains offending class: javax.ejb.EJB" when deploying EJB project

Tags: java, ejb, apache-tomee

When I deployed my web apps with EJB 3.0, I saw this warning:

```
WARNING: jar 'E:\mws\MCDS\portal\portal-web\target\portal-web-1.0.0\WEB-INF\lib\ejb-api-3.0.jar' contains offending class: javax.ejb.EJB. It will be ignored.
```

My web apps started normally but I want to know why warning appeared and would it be a serious problems.

Im new for EJB and maybe this is dumb question. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this warning because you have included the `ejb-api-3.0.jar` in your application. The classes in this jar are provided by the server implementation that you're using, so should not be packaged in your application.

§15.2.1 of the Servlet (3.0/3.1) Specification states that:

> Servlet containers that are part of a Java EE product should not allow the application to override Java SE or Java EE platform classes, such as those in java.* and javax.* namespaces, that either Java SE or Java EE do not allow to be modified.